# Cross-database relations using UUID for PK

Tags: django, database, postgresql

It says here that foreignkeys across databases can't be done because of referential integrity: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations

Could this be overcome by using UUID's for the primary key?

I'm guessing either I don't fully understand referential integrity, or I'm not the first to think of this and it can't be done for reasons I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key means "make sure a value in this column exists in another column". This doesn't work cross-database in PostgreSQL, as databases cannot "see" each other. It does work cross-schema though - use the fully qualified schema_name.table_name.

Why are you trying to refer to a column in another database?

Comment: I see, so if one side were deleted, the other database would never know until an error occurred? I have an address model that requires postgis, and I want only that to use the postgis db backend. Not a big deal, just thought it would be better somewhat isolated.

Comment: @DavidTan you can take actions if the foreign side is deleted such as delete the other row or set it null or do nothing. See "on delete cascade"